# Knockout JS - Setting table width based on an observable field

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, observable

I am building a web page with a table showing transactions.

The table has a drop-down menu which is used to select the transaction type to display. A table with one row contains this drop-down menu, which needs to be aligned to show at the right edge of the transaction table. Other filter fields are present, depending on the transaction type, and these start from the left side of the table's single row.

Depending on the transaction type, the table's width changes.

I created an observable field in my view model which equals the current width of the table.

The following markup defines this layout, with only one filter - the dropdown selection of transaction type.

```
<fieldset id="transactionFilters">
<table data-bind="width: TransactionGridWidth">
<!-- I also tried the following:
  <table data-bind="style: {width: TransactionGridWidth}">
  I tried appending "px" to the width field as well, with no change.
-->
<tr>
  <th style="width: 350px">
    <div class="dropdown" style="margin: 10px 0 10px 15px">
      <div align="right">
        <span style="padding: 10px">View&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
            <span id="dropdownTitle" >Type 1</span>
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Type 1</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Type 2</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Type 3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </th>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

One of the following grids will be shown at a time, each with a different width:

```
<div id="type1TransactionsGrid" style="width: 1000px;"></div>
<div id="type2TransactionsGrid" style="width: 800px; display: none;"></div>
<div id="type3TransactionsGrid" style="width: 1200px; display: none;"></div>
```

The following KnockoutJS script defines the observable:

```
var ViewModel = {
  Type1TransactionsGrid: ko.observable(),
  Type2TransactionsGrid: ko.observable(),
  Type3TransactionsGrid: ko.observable(),
  TransactionGridWidth: ko.observable(),
  OnLoad: function () {
      ViewModel.TransactionGridWidth(1000);//initialisation
  }
};
...//rest of the implementation
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
ViewModel.OnLoad();
```

I've got a switch-case which selects which transaction grid to display, and sets TransactionGridWidth to the current grid width, like so:

```
ViewModel.TransactionGridWidth(document.getElementById('Type1TransactionsGrid')).getBoundingClientRect().width);
```

I am certain this works, as I show the value of the field on-screen, and it tracks changes.  The debugger confirms that the observable holds the correct width of the transaction grid.

No matter what I do, I can't get the table's width to change with the observable value.  It works if I put in explicit size, e.g.

```
    <table width="1000px">
```

TLDR:
I've got an observable variable which successfully tracks the width of the currently displayed transaction grid, but data-binding this variable to my filter table's style does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you try to append `px` to your value?

Comment: I tried that - no change.  Will edit my question to show this.

Comment: sometimes I find the the style binding just doesn't work and fallback to attr ---- attr: { style: 'width: '+ somevalue + 'px' }, probably make a complete working example in something like jsfiddle if you want working answer.

Comment: also worth noting that the table element width will push out to 100% of it container if the content requires it.

Comment: Aren't you meant to use the data-bind on those 3 div elements instead of fixed width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely works to use the `style` binding to set the width of a table. My guess is that there is some part of it you're doing wrong, but it's not clear from your question what that is.

```js
function ViewModel() {
  this.tableWidth = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table style="border: 1px solid black" data-bind="style: {width: tableWidth() + 'px'}">
  <tr>
    <td>Some content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>
  <select data-bind="value: tableWidth, options: [200, 300, 400]"></select>
</p>
```